# CPU occupancy shows 100%

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, cpu

I have a scenario of reader-writers from/to a common buffer. All writer threads have highest priority than the reader thread. The reader thread activation function is in continuous while loop if there is any data in the buffer it reads all contents at shot and calls sche_yield() function.

In this scenario I expected CPU utilisation is some where 20 to 30% but it shows 100%(Linux top command) but after little more digging out I realised that the reader thread after reading the data it get added at the end of scheduling queue and there are no writers to write data, the reader again scheduled and it again yields and get added at the end of scheduling queue and this is coninously repeating and due to this CPU shows 100%.

I feel there should be an event handling meachanism rather than the reader in the while loop continously cheking data. Could you help how to write event handling(there should be an indication to reader thread when writer threads write data) which is platform and OS independent ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide code samples.

Comment: Rather than busy-waiting in the reader thread, the writer(s) should [signal a condition](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) that unlocks the mutex the reader is waiting on.

Comment: Also - unless you are very careful about ensuring that writers don't access the same region of the buffer, and won't update the buffer while a reader is active, you will get race conditions.

Comment: In the reader's loop put something like `if (incoming_data_len == 0) sleep(5)` and the CPU load will go down.

Comment: In my experiment even sleep for 100 milli seconds by reader thread causing buffer flow by writer threads and at the same I can not have offered to have huge buffer to avoid buffer flow by writers.

Comment: Yes, because yield is essentially useless.

Comment: NO SLEEP for inter-thread comms and/or data flow-control.  It's suggestions like this that result in 'sleep() is always wrong' posts etc.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should use a synchronization primitive that would allow the reader thread to wait until the work actually appears instead of doing a busy loop. This can be solved with a synchronization primitive called condition variable.

If C is the only option you have you can either use the `cnd_t` condition variable introduced by the [C11 thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread), but this can be not supported on older compilers. In that case you still have the `pthread_cond_t` with all the synchronization functions like `pthread_cond_wait` / `pthread_cond_signal` but I am not aware if the Windows feature called "Pthread Support in Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX Version 3.5" that supports the POSIX thread stuff on Windows is not considered legacy. However you should be able to make a thin wrapper around Windows `HANDLE` objects that would mimic the behavior of POSIX condition variables.

If you can use C++ then you could use a [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) introduced by C++11.

**Notes on support of C11**

Since you mentioned you needed platform independent mechanism it should be noted that C11 is not supported in MSVC 2012 (which I can at least verify myself) and links about MSVC 2015 (e.g. [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx)) mostly hint that it is not supported there as well.

Comment: I dont see [tag:c++] tag on the question

Comment: @Nazar554 thank you for pointing that out, adjusted the answer so that it covers both C and C++.

Comment: Because you mentioned C++11 threads, maybe it is worth to add some info about C11 [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/cnd_init)?

Comment: @Nazar554 The use of `sched_yield()` suggests that OP is using pthreads. (`thrd_yield()` is its equivalent in C11).

Comment: @Nazar554 thanks for the information, I have actually been so neglectant towards C that I was not aware about C11. Interesting at which version if any MSVC supports this.

Comment: Visual Studio has notoriously poor support for C in general. You'll likely have to wait 10 years for them to implement C11 and an eternity for them to implement a decent conforming compiler.

Comment: @Lundin well since they are already struggling with C++11/14/17 I would imagine that C11 is the last thing on the roadmap :(

Comment: Right now I am testing the code in linux platform, but as I said earlier I have to make this code as generic and OS independent by removing the call 'sched_yield()'. I can not use any POSIX specific calls as my code is supposed ro run on other embeded platform RTOSs like ThreadX etc. Other embedded compilers may not have support C11 thread support library. So, I seek help in making the solution generic and independent of across platforms.

Comment: @user3899508 I understand, I'm not very well aware of how RTOS do these kinds of things but since even POSIX is a no go why not make your own synchronization primitive that would simply wrap the corresponding functionality of the platform?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe (in the second paagraph) is a reasonably way to expect a typical scheduling: when a process/thread gives up CPU, it goes back to the end of the queue.

What you can do instead is to make the writer thread(s) signal the reader when the data is placed in the queue using a *conditional variable* rather than using an infinite loop for the reader.

Using [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) the reader can wait for the data to become available and using [`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) the writer(s) would notify the reader than the data is ready.

Comment: I can not use any POSIX thread specific calls as my code has to run across different embedded platforms which will have different OS and processor architectures.

Comment: C11 threads is an option? It's not fully supported on most platforms. So POSIX threads is portable at least on nix-y systems and probably the only portable way to implement threads in C as things stand at the moment.